# jar won't be executed

Tags: java, jar

I tried to run my javaprojekt via

```
java -jar myproject.jar
```

and got:

```
Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from myproject.jar
```

How can this be? I got my jar pretty much out of the box, using Netbeans

Ok, I found something that looks as if it could be a manifest file, so here it is:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: someone
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_25
```

Ok, so here is the class:

```
public class Starter {

    private static Control c;

    /**
    *
    * @param 
    */
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        Control c = new Control();
    }

    public static Control getC() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Howsoever, even ignoring the jar, if I try

```
java -cp myproject.jar control.Starter
```

I get a classNotFoundException

It does however work fine when I start from inside Netbeans.

Ok, apparently I got a default class with a main in it when I first created the project. 
I only now deleted that class and did clean and build again.

This means my manifest looks now like:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
Created-By: Apache Maven
Built-By: someone
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_25
Main-Class: default.Starter
```

For one, I wonder how this happend because Starter is clearly in package control, not in package default.

For another, I still get:

```
  Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from myproject.jar
```

Can someone help me?

Well, if I try to compile with java -cp and so on I get an Exception:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: control/Starter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:634)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: control.Starter. Program will exit.
```

Can someone answer me just this, please:

Is this usually a bug in the project or one somewhere else? 
Meaning, if I try to build the same project on an other computer with supposedly correct paths, would I have better chances of success?
Is it possible that I managed to write code that cannot possibly be made an executable jar?

Comment: Provide the manifest file and the package of the boot class file and we can tell you if it was set up right. Also, make sure there was an empty line at the end of the manifest file before constructing the jar.

Comment: What is a manifest file? Actually I thought an IDE was to make sure one does not have to think about such things.

Comment: manifest file is there I think. What is a boot class? Oh, and yes, there is an empty line.

Comment: the boot class is the class that contains the `public static void main(String[])` method.

Comment: @newnewbie You need to explicitly tell the IDE to make an executable JAR file. (See: https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html#Exercise_1)

Comment: Some more information above

Comment: @newnewbie can you post the package declaration in the class `Starter`? is it `package control;` ?

Comment: What do you mean by package declaration? the name of the package? that would be control

Comment: @newnewbie package declaration is - if one is present - the first line in a java file, it statrts with `package` and ends with the semicolon `;`. The fully qualified package name is that between those two boundaries. If you type `java -cp myproject.jar <fully qualified package>.Starter` and still get `classNotFoundException` then the jar file `myproject.jar` does not contain the class `<fully qualified package>.Starter`. You can open the jar file with you favourite zip tool and browse  it to find out whether the class is there or not.

Comment: ans I just looked into the jar, Starter.class is there - in a package named control

Comment: or do the <> have to be there too?

Comment: Edit: I now get another error when I try the java -cp thing, look into edit for that

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the main class in your manifest file

```
Main-Class: <package>.Starter
```

or you can run your jar as it is by passing the main class with

```
java -cp myproject.jar <package>.Starter
```

In both cases the main class has to be fully qualified i.e. `<package-name>.<class-name>`

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the `Main-Class` parameter.

When `java -jar` tries to execute a jar, it can't figure out which method contains the `main` method. Multiple classes could contain it, so differentiating isn't possible. To counter this problem, you must specify the `Main-Class` parameter in the manifest.

Adding a: `Main-Class: Starter` will fix it.

Comment: sounds gut but apparently I cannot write into the manifest file....how can I change that?

Comment: You should be able to. Try making your own Manifest file, a simple text-editor will do this, or by changing the properties of the manifest file inside netbeans.

Comment: I try. Netbeans tells me it is read only because it is inside the jar

Comment: I can write a new manifest.mf BUT netbeans wont have it in the same folder as the old one. I can not overwrite the old one, nor change its properties nor delete it. Can that be fixed?

Comment: help    please? Could I avoid that by asking a friend to make the jar in eclipse?

Comment: You can change the jar-creation settings in the IDE itself. I don't use netbeans personally, so I have little insight on how to do that.

Comment: java -cp myproject.jar control.Starter will not work either, do you have any idea about that